# Combine all columns from a point onwards in Pandas / Python

Tags: python, pandas

Its probably incredibly simple but I just cant find the right wording to search in the documentation.

I have a single dataframe.

This dataframe is created by a spreadsheet I load. Sometimes the spreadsheet has Items1, Items2, Items3 as columns, sometimes it only has Items1 (this depends on the max quantity of items ordered by a customer, each items gets its own column.).

**I'm trying to combine all of these to a master column, "Final Order", which would list the contents of Items1 ----> the last column (I dont want to enter this information in each time, I just want the code to determine how many columns there are and have at it.)**

Example:

```
Order Number  |  Name  |  Item1  |  Item2  |  Item3
 7571983219      Jim      Socks     Shoes      Hat
```

Output:

```
Order Number  |  Name  |  Item1  |  Item2  |  Item3 |  Final Order
 7571983219      Jim      Socks     Shoes      Hat     Socks,Shoes,Hat
```

If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['Final Order'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(','.join, 1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Order Number Name  Item1  Item2 Item3      Final Order
0    7571983219  Jim  Socks  Shoes   Hat  Socks,Shoes,Hat
```

This assumes that the last *n-2* rows are the ones to join. As an alternative you can exclude the rows `Order Number` and `Name`:

```
columns = [column for column in df.columns if column not in ["Order Number", "Name"]]
df['Final Order'] = df[columns].apply(','.join, 1)
```

The expression:

```
','.join
```

is a function that joins a sequence of strings by `,`.

If you have missing values, for example like in the DataFrame below:

```
   Order Number Name  Item1 Item2 Item3 Final Order
0    7571983219  Jim  Socks   NaN   Hat   Socks,Hat
```

do the following:

```
df['Final Order'] = df[columns].apply(lambda x: ','.join(xi for xi in x if isinstance(xi, str)), 1)
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but I am getting this error: results[i] = self.f(v)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found

Comment: @BigSecret Can you see if you have some missing value? NaN I mean

Comment: I definitely do. If Customer A ordered 5 items, but customer B only ordered 1, there will be 4 columns with NaN Values in them for customer B. Unfortunately this is the only way I could get this to work. I have two sheets, one with orders, one with line items. I had to match and pivot the two just to get to where I am now.

Comment: @BigSecret added an alternative for missing values

Comment: Thank you! And I actually just wrote something in to take all NaNs and fill them with "" instead.

Comment: @BigSecret I thought about that also but I think it will leave you two contiguous commas for missing values. something like `socks,,hat`

Comment: So far, we're good - but last thing I cant get: It wont start at column Items1. That is index 12, and its pulling in everything. I've changed [columns] to [12:] but its still grabbing everything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225498/discussion-between-dani-mesejo-and-big-secret).

Comment: After chatting, we got it!

Solution by @Dani Masejo - 
df['Final Order'] = df.iloc[:, 12:].apply(lambda x: ','.join(xi for xi in x if isinstance(xi, str)), 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
dataframe['Final Order'] = ','.join((dataframe[c] for c in dataframe.columns[3:]))
```

which creates a tuple of Items and joins them by a colon.

Comment: How does this know to start at Items1? I ask because my actual dataframe has many columns. This is just an example.

Comment: @BigSecret my bad, forgot to add the slice :) now, you select all columns except the first three, which I assumed from your description to always be `order`, `number` and `name`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one rows. Please `melt` the dataframe, `groupby` and `join` columns with `items`. Lets try

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Order Number','Name'], value_vars=['Item1','Item2','Item3']).groupby(['Order_Number','Name'])['value'].apply(', '.join).to_frame('Final Order')


                           Final Order
Order Number    Name    
7571983219      Jim    Socks, Shoes, Hat
```

Comment: can I select id_vars = based on indexing? This df is larger than whats listed, and has many rows. So instead of listing 'order number' & 'name', I do [:11] (everything to include) and value_vars=[12:]?

Comment: I think you can. pd. melt, select indexes before you group by

Comment: Happy to help if you added more data that would allow selection on index and specified the required outcome